# Display result at same page as form in codeigniter, undefined variable

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I'm learning codeIgniter by making a booking system. When having the result showing on a different page it all went fint, but when putting it on the same page (which is how I want it) `$rooms_form_options` and `$packages_form_options` gets undefined after the form being submitted

```
<div>
    <?php echo form_label('Conference Room', 'id') ; ?>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('id', $rooms_form_options, set_value('id')); ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo form_label('Package type', 'package_id') ; ?>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('package_id', $packages_form_options, set_value('package_id')); ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo form_label('Antal deltagare', 'number_people') ; ?>
    <?php echo form_input('number_people', set_value('number_people')) ; ?>
</div>

<div>
    <?php echo form_submit('preview', 'Book'); ?>
</div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["preview"])) {
if($messages) {
    echo html_escape($messages);
} else {
?>

<div class="alert alert-success">Number of participants:  <?php echo    html_escape($guests); ?> </div>
<div class="alert alert-success">Room:  <?php echo html_escape($room); ?>   </div>
<div class="alert alert-success">Package:  <?php echo html_escape($package); ?> </div>
<div class="alert alert-success">Price per participant: <?php echo html_escape($price); ?> </div>
<div class="alert alert-success">Total Price: <?php echo html_escape($guests*$price); ?> </div>
<?php } }?>
```

This is where I get `$rooms_form_options` and `$packages_form_options` from:

```
    public function index() {

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('bootstrap/header');

    $this->load->model('Booking_Model');
    $rooms = $this->Booking_Model->get();
    $rooms_form_options = array();


    foreach ($rooms as $id => $room) {
        $rooms_form_options[$id] = $room->title;
    }


    $this->load->model('Package_Model');
    $packages = $this->Package_Model->get();
    $packages_form_options = array();

    foreach ($packages as $id => $package) {
        $packages_form_options[$id] = $package->package_name;
    }

    $this->load->view('booking', array(
        'rooms_form_options' => $rooms_form_options,
        'packages_form_options' => $packages_form_options,
    ));


    $this->load->view('bootstrap/footer');

}
```

I handle the form in method called `preview` and here's where I point back to the booking page:

```
    // load view with people, room and package values
    $this->load->view('bootstrap/header');
    $this->load->view('booking', array(
        'guests' => $guests,
        'room' => $room_title,
        'package' => $package_title,
        'alias' => $package_alias,
        'price' => $price,
        'messages' => $messages,

    ));
```

How do I make sure that `$rooms_form_options` and `$package_form_options` are defined after the form been submitted?

Comment: I just changed the post making it a bit clear, `$rooms_form_options` and `$package_form_options` gets undefined after submitting the form

Comment: So you are doing it without ajax right??

Comment: That's correct. Not so familiar with ajax.

Comment: But if that's the best solution I would like to learn how I can do it in this case?

Comment: So you submit the form, to another controller method, and these two variable is not defined in that method view?

Comment: @Iamzozo Correct, I get that this is the problem, but I don't know how to again reach those values in the `index` method and I don't want to repeat the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another, separate method to populate these variables:

```
private function get_options() {

    $this->load->model('Booking_Model');
    $rooms = $this->Booking_Model->get();
    $rooms_form_options = array();

    foreach ($rooms as $id => $room) {
        $rooms_form_options[$id] = $room->title;
    }

    $this->load->model('Package_Model');
    $packages = $this->Package_Model->get();
    $packages_form_options = array();

    foreach ($packages as $id => $package) {
        $packages_form_options[$id] = $package->package_name;
    }

    return array(
        'packages_form_options' => $packages_form_options,
        'rooms_form_options' => $rooms_form_options,
    );
}
```

The whole will look like this:

```
public function index() {

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('bootstrap/header');

    $options = $this->get_options();

    $this->load->view('booking', array(
        'guests' => '',
        'room' => '',
        'package' => '',
        'alias' => '',
        'price' => '',
        'messages' => '',
        'rooms_form_options' => $options['packages_form_options'],
        'packages_form_options' => $options['rooms_form_options'],
    ));

    $this->load->view('bootstrap/footer');
}

public function preview() {

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('bootstrap/header');

    $options = $this->get_options();

    $this->load->view('booking', array(
        'guests' => $this->input->post('guests'),
        'room' => $this->input->post('room_title'),
        'package' => $this->input->post('package_title'),
        'alias' => $this->input->post('package_alias'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
        'messages' => $this->input->post('messages'),
        'rooms_form_options' => $options['packages_form_options'],
        'packages_form_options' => $options['rooms_form_options'],
    ));

    $this->load->view('bootstrap/footer');
}

private function get_options() {

    $this->load->model('Booking_Model');
    $rooms = $this->Booking_Model->get();
    $rooms_form_options = array();

    foreach ($rooms as $id => $room) {
        $rooms_form_options[$id] = $room->title;
    }

    $this->load->model('Package_Model');
    $packages = $this->Package_Model->get();
    $packages_form_options = array();

    foreach ($packages as $id => $package) {
        $packages_form_options[$id] = $package->package_name;
    }

    return array(
        'packages_form_options' => $packages_form_options,
        'rooms_form_options' => $rooms_form_options,
    );
}
```

Comment: How should I load the view again in index?

Comment: I don't get an error now, but instead nothing happens

Comment: It's the same as you wrote it. So in your index, you can skip what is in `get_options` private method. Also you should call this again, in your `preview` method to pass these values to your view again. Currently, in your example, you are not adding `packages_form_options` and `rooms_form_options` to your views in your **preview** method.

Comment: Nothing happens when I submit now... No error or no result

Comment: Still nothing happens.

Comment: Got a full blank page or what?

Comment: No I get the same page, everything stays the same

Comment: And alerts (preview) at the bottom of the form are not displaying?

Comment: Nope! Everything stays the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89812/discussion-between-iamzozo-and-teninchhero).