# Converting Plain PHP code to codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have created a dropdown in plain php that really works and I want it to apply also in my codeigniter project but I don't know how. I tried but the code does not work. This is the plain php to be converted to codeigniter:
The main page:

```
<select id="operationName" name="operationName">
<option value="">-SELECT-</option>
<?php while($rs = $query->fetch())
{
extract($rs);
?>
<option value="<?php echo $OperationName;?>"><?php echo $OperationName;?>   </option>
<?php
}
?>
 </select>
<input type="text" id="deldays" name="deldays" >
<div id="deldays"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#operationName').change(function(){
    $.get('trial.php',{q:$(this).val()},function(data){
        $('#deldays').val(data);
    });
});
});
```

and here is the php function that is being called:

```
if(isset($_GET['q']))
{
$days = $_GET['q'];
try{
$qry = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM operation WHERE OperationName = :opt");
$qry->bindParam(':opt',$days);
$qry->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
exit();
}
while($rs = $qry->fetch())
{
extract($rs);
echo $DeliveryDays;
}
}
```

Comment: [Teach yourself how to use CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/).

Comment: I already know the basic of codeigniter and my rpoblem is that I cannot somehow implement this code to it. I am having problem with returning the value from controller to ajax.....

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Comment: I am able to grasp the answer of @keronkonk but can you give me more readable code for model because I am a bit confused in what he'd done.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must know the concept of MVC, which codeigniter use

M is model (folder application/model) = the database operation

V is view (folder application/view) = the view, html, css, script etc.

C is controller (folder application/controller) = the page handler

this following page, which have the query, better if inserted in model

save it in folder application/model, with name m_operation.php

```
<?php
class Operation extends CI_Model {
    //table name
    private $operation = 'operation';
    function Operation() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('file');
    }
    function allOperation( $days ) {
        $this->db->where('OperationName', $days);
        return $this->db->get($operation)->result();                
    }
}
?>
```

this following page is view, save it in folder application/view, with name v_operation.php

```
<select id="operationName" name="operationName">
<option value="">-SELECT-</option>
<?php 
foreach ($operation as $row) {
    echo "<option value = '". $row->OperationName ."'>".
            $row->OperationName .
        "</option>";
}
?>
</select>


<input type="text" id="deldays" name="deldays" >
<div id="deldays"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#operationName').change(function(){
    $.get('trial.php',{q:$(this).val()},function(data){
        $('#deldays').val(data);
    });
});
});
```

this following page is controller, save it in folder application/controller, with name operation.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Operation extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');// Load Helper URL CI
        $this->load->model('m_operation');// load the model
    }

    public function index() {
        if(isset($this->input->get('q'))) {
            $days = $this->input->get('q');
            $data['operation'] = $this->m_operation->allOperation($days);       
            $this->load->view('v_operation', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

you can access the webpage with the name of controller, like this

yoursitename.com/index.php/operation

Comment: I'm a bit confused in the model that you posted... it's different from how i write my query....

Comment: How can I apply this code to mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607483/display-result-at-same-page-as-form-in-codeigniter-undefined-variable ?.

Comment: I think you forgot something to include, how can I display the data for DeliveryDays in textfield.....

Answer (score 0):

I found a wok around in my problem please check the code for future reference:

controller:

```
$operation = explode(',',$this->input->post('operationName'));
        foreach($operation as $val)
        {
            $opName = trim($operation[0]);
            $days = trim($operation[1]);
        }
```

model:

```
function get_operation()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('operation');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();

    return $result;
}
```

view:

```
<select class="form-control" id="operationName" name="operationName" >
       <option value="">-SELECT-</option>
        <?php
         foreach($operation as $val)
         {
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $val['OperationName'].','.$val['DeliveryDays'];?>"><?php echo $val['OperationName'];?></option>
          <?php
         }
      ?>
      </select>
```